# WP_Query filtering

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've been looking around here and other sites for a solution. I found lots of really helpfull posts but for some reason I just cant get this to work.

What I have:
WP posts with custom fields.
One is "rating" which is given a number between 1-5
The other is "flash" with either a 1 or a 0.

What I want to do:
Show all posts with a 1 on flash, in ORDER descending by the "rating"...

I currently have:

```
 $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'    => 11,
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'meta_key'          => 'rating',
                    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order'             => 'DESC',
                    'meta_query'        => array(
                        'meta_key'          => 'flash',
                        'meta_value'        => '1',
                    )
                );
                $ultimos = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This does NOT filter the flash custom field.
however if I do:

```
$args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'    => 11,
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'meta_key'          => 'rating',
                    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order'             => 'DESC',
                    'meta_key'          => 'flash',
                    'meta_value'        => '1',
                );
                $ultimos = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This DOES filter flash, but does not order them properly.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to take a look at using the relationship feature of the WP_Query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

`$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 11,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_key'          => 'rating',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'flash',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    );
$ultimos = new WP_Query( $args );`

Comment: Hey, this did the trick! thanks!
I just had to change the OR to AND and it worked perfectly